# Xamarin visual studio filenotfoundException Windows.winmd

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

I'm creating a Portable Xamarin.Forms project, and I just added some pages I had on my shared project fixing errors.

After the edits, the project doesn't compile with the error

> Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com. Reason: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly "Windows.winmd, Version=, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Pheraps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
>
> Project: *myproject.Droid*

Plus others 4670 errors like this:

> file .winmd "Windows.winmd" contains type 'Windows.Storage.Streams.IDataWriter'. Windows namespace usage is reserved.
>
> Project: *myproject.WinPhone*

Any error has a different type and they all refers to the WinPhone project.

I tryed checking in the Droid references for the *Mono.Android* but this is the scenario:
[image]

*(the selected one was thicked, i deselected it for testing, but still same error)*

What can I do?

Thanks all

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks for replying, but why i'm getting the error if it doesn't exists? I tryed to clean - compile - close - reopen project but still got the error

Comment: `Windows.winmd` does not exist for `Xamarin.Android`, you either with that improperly referenced in a shared project  or dependent assembly that is including it and thus pulled into the build

Comment: I had an "using windows" line in a page, I solved removing it. thanks!

Comment: That would do it. Happy Xammie Coding ;-)